# How to create a Sitecore Analytics Reporting DB

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.5

We've got a Sitecore 7.5 installation where we did not deploy any xDB features. There's no Mongo DB or Analytics reporting DBs. We're now exploring upgrading to 8 and turning on these features. I'm doing a test upgrade on a dev server. I've got the Mongo DB set up, but there currently is no Analytics DB in SQL. How do I go about creating that DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you download Sitecore 8 from https://dev.sitecore.net/ there is a zip of the webroot (e.g. from [this page](https://dev.sitecore.net/en/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/8_0/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_8_update2.aspx)). Once you download that webroot zip, you can find the `Sitecore.Analytics.mdf` and `Sitecore.Analytics.ldf` files within the `\Databases\` folder.